# Query shortest path from coordinates with pgrouting

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

How do I calculate the path, pass coordinates and, if possible, in the return function, have the route coordinate list?
(I'm trying to plot the route with the ipyleaflet library in a jupyter notebook, and I need the return of the route's coordinate list. I'm new to this and I don't know how to do it)

I tried with an example query that I searched for in a book
but I got an empty answer

```
SELECT r.seq, r.node, w.name As street, w.x1, w.x2, r.cost::numeric(10,4), ( SUM(w.length_m) OVER(ORDER BY r.seq) )::numeric(10,2) As dist_m 
FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid AS id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM ways', (SELECT id FROM ways_vertices_pgr ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID( ST_Point(-3.7482, -38.5486), 4326) limit 1 ) , (SELECT id FROM ways_vertices_pgr 
ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID( ST_Point(-3.7532, -38.5170), 4326) limit 1 ), true) AS r 
LEFT JOIN ways AS w ON r.edge = w.gid;
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, I tried with an example query that I searched for in a book. 



 SELECT r.seq, r.node, w.name As street, w.x1, w.x2,  r.cost::numeric(10,4),
( SUM(w.length_m) OVER(ORDER BY r.seq) )::numeric(10,2) As dist_m 
FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid AS id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM ways',
(SELECT id FROM ways_vertices_pgr ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID( ST_Point(-3.7482, -38.5486), 4326) limit 1 ) ,
(SELECT id FROM ways_vertices_pgr ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID( ST_Point(-3.7532, -38.5170), 4326) limit 1 ), true) 
AS r LEFT JOIN ways AS w ON r.edge = w.gid;

Comment: What was the result of the query and how does it differ from what you expected.   Are you wanting to run the SQL query as part of the Python code?  Please edit the question to add more detail

Comment: I got an empty answer.
ok i will add more information in the question

Comment: There can be a lot of hickups. Is pgrouting extension correctly installed and enabled? Maybe your library silently ignore SQL errors and return just empty response instead of them. Pgrouting (and routing in general) also expect properly noded network dataset (junction on each intersection, start/end node ID on each segment and so on). So is your dataset a proper network? At last, it can also be a logical error in your SQL.

Comment: @DavidP

I imported the data using osm2pgrouting. The problem I'm having is finding the node id.
I'm using this query:
select id from ways_vertices_pgr as vertices order by  vertices.the_geom <-> ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(-3.7106, -38.5931),4326) LIMIT 1;    

but I always get the same id in return

Comment: It's a very good idea to invest a few hours to do the workshop, because it should give you an idea how pgRouting works: https://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.5/en/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query if it works

```
     with source_tmp as (SELECT source 
            FROM ways order by st_distance(the_geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-38.5486,-3.7482), 4326)) limit 1),
    target_tmp as (SELECT target 
            FROM ways order by st_distance(the_geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-38.5170,-3.7532), 4326)) limit 1)

SELECT * 
FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid AS id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM ways', (SELECT source from source_tmp) , 
                  (SELECT target from  target_tmp), true) AS r 
LEFT JOIN ways AS w ON r.edge = w.gid;
```

What I did here is selected source and target initially using lat long, you have to reverse the order in your st_makepoint function. Then I can the query

Comment: Yes, it worked!!
thanks @Arun !!